# How to get value from sales_flat_order_item table using quote_item_id?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sales-order, quoteitem

Using the `sales_order_place_after` event in my custom Observer.
I have the `quote_item_id` value (example 324).
**How to** get the corresponding `item_id` value from the `sales_flat_order_item` table?

I am able to successfully use getCollection method, but it returns the order item as an array.
(**$sales_order_item_id** in below example)

How to get the string value? Eg **224** in example table
(in an efficient manner)

```
class Custom_Model_Observer {
 public function booking(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $OrderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId(); //order entity id        
    $QuoteObject = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote(); //quote object

    foreach ($QuoteObject->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {

      //get the quote item id - in example $quote_itemId = 324
      $quote_itemId = $item->getData('item_id');

      //get data from sales_flat_order_item table
      $sales_order_item_id = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
       ->getCollection()
       ->addFieldToFilter('quote_item_id', $quote_itemId)
       ->getData('item_id');
     //do more stuff here

    }
  }
}
```

Example **sales_flat_order_item** table:

[image: sales_flat_order_item table]

Comment: $sales_order_item_id = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quote_item_id', $quote_itemId)->getItemId();

Comment: Did already try that, but not working. Code stops dead, no log error, no exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can also use **getColumnValues($colName)**

this also returns array, within which value would be $sales_order_item_id[0]

```
$sales_order_item_id = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
       ->getCollection()
       ->addFieldToFilter('quote_item_id', $quote_itemId)
       ->getColumnValues('item_id');
```

https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024829/Using+Magento+1.x+collections

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can iterate through the order item collection and get both - the `item_id` and the `quote_item_id` in one loop, like this

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $orderItem){
    //quote_item_id
    $orderItem->getQuoteItemId();
    //item_id
    $orderItem->getId();
}
```

But I'm not sure that there already exist the `item_id` in the event you are using, `sales_order_place_after`.
That id is available only after the order and the order items are saved in the database. The right event for accessing that data would be `sales_order_save_after`.

Comment: in your example (using sales_order_save_after event), does `$orderItem->getId();` get the **order id**, or the **order item id**?
I was able to extract the 'item_id' by using `$orderitem_id_value = $sales_order_item_id[0]['item_id'];` from the array, but this seems so inefficient. I will test your suggestion.

Comment: `$orderItem->getId()` is the order item id. `$order->getId()` would be the order id.

Comment: I'm not able to use both foreach without refactoring code (too much effort, too little time), and as my method is working, I will stick to it. Will up vote your useful suggestion. Let me know if you think deserves more credit etc.